# What's the best way for the user to add multiple details to single area of input?

Tags: php, jquery

In my project the user has to detail his management expenses in four different areas. At first we had a simple table ([this one](http://85.94.221.106/table.html)) where he had to write all the data grouping all the expenses description in a textarea, now we want him to detail each area, so i have to give the user the possibility to add "rows" to each area. That means that if his "Impegni" expenses consists of three entries he must enter three "rows".

My idea is to use jquery to let the user add rows and modify the rowspan of the first column when the user adds/remove a row (that is, if you need to enter another row for "Impegni" i create a new row under  the third row and add "colspan=2" to the "impegni" cell) but maybe there is a better way to handle this kind of input.

I try to explain it even better: the four rows that are present in my table are the "master" areas and the user must add details to those areas. Creating new "sub-rows" for each area it's an idea,  but maybe there is a better way to handle it!

EDIT - another idea is to have four different tables (one for each one of the "master" rows) and show hide them with tabs (look at example five on [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/dynamic.html) page) but i don't know how to handle the sum of all the rows

What do you suggest?

Comment: Is "Impegni" an input field? You shouldn't rely on the user to add *just the right amount of rows.* Instead you should add them automatically based on the "Impegni" whatever that means -- we are a english speaking website ;-)

Comment: Why not use buttons indicating each action e.g. add new row, or column, and it will do exactly that, don't worry much about the rowspan and colspan coz you can leave them empty or better still, check them if `:empty` in jquery and remove the border on the left and simple manipulation don't over think it,and clone them :)

Comment: "Impegni" it's one of the 'header' row in the example table. I need to give the user the possibility to add new data related to each one of those 4 "master" rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend has made a plugin for it, [you can look here](http://www.re9studio.com.br/demo/jquery_-_adicionar_e_remover_campos_do_formulario/).

Answer (score 0):

I think jquery is the best way, you can access your database with simple ajax command from jquery, like .load()
:)